# Memory management issue when dealing with core foundation classes

Tags: ios, memory, addressbook

I have a memory management problem that i can't seem to find a solution for. The code is as follow:

```
-(ABRecordRef)convertABCPerson:(ABCPerson*) person{

// create new address book person record
ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate(); 

[self setValuesFor:person toARecord:aRecord];

return aRecord;
```

}

So i convert my own class to a ABRecordRef and now I need somehow to "autorelease" this object(So i can take ownership in a different object). I am using ARC and a ABRecordRef cannot be toll-bridged to a Cocoa foundation class. Any ideas how i could solve this memory management issue ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Post the answer to your own question and accept it, otherwise this will stay in the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The only thing i had to do is cast it to id and using bridge transfer to let ARC handle the memory management. From an other class you can do a ABRecordRef cast as __bridge so that ARC handles the record correctly.

The solution:

```
-(id)convertABCPerson:(ABCPerson*) person{

    // create new address book person record
    ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate(); 

    [self setValuesFor:person toARecord:aRecord];

    id record = (__bridge_transfer id)aRecord;

    return record;
}
```

The casting back:

```
personViewController.displayedPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[[ABCFacade sharedABCFacade] convertABCPerson:goldenRecord];
```